MAC MYSQL run time errors 2024
Hi Have tried to install MYSQL through home brew and through the DMG package. I have installed 8.4. in the system settings when I try to start mysql it starts for a second then stops.
When I tried to start it in my terminal I get two errors
mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)

or
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
.Logging to '/usr/local/mysql-8.0.39-macos14-arm64/data/MacBook-Pro-8.local.err'.
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql-8.0.39-macos14-arm64/data/MacBook-Pro-8.local.pid).
rossrawlins@MacBook-Pro-8 ~ % 

Those files just dont exist after installation and I am not sure how to resolve this simple issue.
When I run
sudo brew services start mysql the terminal says its running, but I am unable to set or use the local set up.

Home brew was installing 9.0.1 and the client was 8.24 I ran a FULL clean to clear ALL instances of every mysql on my device. I then installed 8.4 specifically and its working now.
